# WPF: Combine DataTrigger with IsMouseOver

Tags: wpf, triggers, datatrigger

This is my binding data:

```
List<MyData> files;

public clas MyData
{
  public string Name { get; set; }    // Column
  public bool IsOK { get; set; }     // Not a Column
  public string Format { get; set; }  // Column
}
```

My `ListView`:

```
<ListView
    Grid.Row="0"
    Name="lvFiles"
    ItemsSource="{Binding wiresharkFiles}">

<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsOK}" Value="True">
     <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
  </DataTrigger>
  <MultiTrigger>
      <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
          <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
      </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
  </MultiTrigger>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

And i have several `ListViewColumns` because i want to change the color of only the Name column i added this to my other column (Format column) `GridViewColumn`:

```
<GridViewColumn Width="115" Header="Format">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>                                    
        <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock 
                    x:Name="textBlock"
                    Text="{Binding FileFormat}"
                    Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsOK}" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="textBlock" Property="Foreground" Value="Silver"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

This not mark this `Column` (format column) in red but in case `IsMouseIsOver` is `true` this `column` is still in `Silver` and not become `White` like define in my `trigger`.

So i changed my `GridViewColumn` to this:

```
<GridViewColumn Width="115" Header="Format">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>                                    
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock 
                    x:Name="textBlock"
                    Text="{Binding FileFormat}"
                    Margin="0,0,0,0">
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BadCheckSumExist}" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="textBlock" Property="Foreground" Value="Silver"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

But this still not works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your triggers in `ItemContainerStyle`. Just add `Foreground` binding to `TextBlock` that will take foreground brush from `ListViewItem`'s `Foreground`.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="textBlock"
           Text="{Binding FileFormat}"
           Foreground="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}}"
           Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
```

Comment: Where exactly i need to add your example ?, also IsOK is property.

Comment: Obviously in `<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>`. I see the only TextBlock in your code so there is not a lot of places where to insert it :)

Comment: This still not helping, the foreground still not changed

Comment: Did you remove all triggers from `CellTemplate` `DataTemplate` and `TextBlock` `Style`? Place all triggers that change `Foreground` to `ItemContainerStyle`. Also `IsMouseOver` trigger should be the last one in triggers collection.